# sitecore azure module 3.0.0 slow

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-azure

We are using Sitecore Azure module version 3.0.0. We have noticed that it's very slow and stops (hangs) working when deploying db and source files to azure.

Has anyone experienced that and is there any workaround?

Comment: I've started trying to deploy an instance using the Azure module (3.1.0) and am also noticing hangs/timeouts on the upload step.  I have raised it with support and am waiting a response.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Sitecore Azure module version 3.0.0. but with Sitecore 7. 
Deployment from my PC takes about an hour. On my internet connection uploading takes the most time. 
Currently we're looking for a workaround.  If we find I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem.  It is almost certainly either:  a network/connectivity issue OR, the database connection is timing out.  I have blogged about troubleshooting both here:  http://reservoirdevs.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/sitecore-azure-walkthrough-and-gotchas/